# isType(obj) / getType(obj) - v0

Tags: javascript

By `browser unknown`, i mean i don't know how far back support goes for this.

Also, I'm wondering when I can delegate to typeof.

I've heard typeof is faster but the method below is more widely supported and also mentioned in ES5.

```
/*isType
**  dependencies - none
**  browser - unknwon
**
*/
NS.isType = function (type, o) {
    return (Object.prototype.toString.call(o).slice(8,1) === type);
};

/*getType
**  dependencies - none
**  browser - unknown
**
*/
NS.getType = function (o) {
    return (Object.prototype.toString.call(o).slice(8,1);
};
```

**Clarification:**

Not interested in detecting array like objects....just the language objects defined in ES 5.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/constructor-vs-typeof-vs-tostring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
NS.CheckType = function (o,test) {
    // implements both
    return test ? o.constructor.name === test : o.constructor.name;
};
// usage
NS.CheckType(false);       //=> 'Boolean'
NS.CheckType(false,Array); //=> false
NS.CheckType({},Object);   //=> true
NS.CheckType({},Array);    //=> false
NS.CheckType([],Object);   //=> false
NS.CheckType([],Array);    //=> true
NS.CheckType(/[a-z]/);     //=> 'RegExp'
NS.CheckType(0);           //=> 'Number'
// etc...
```

Because most js-things 'inherit' from `Object` you can also use:

```
Object.prototype.is = function (test) {
    return test ? this.constructor === test : this.constructor.name;
};
// usage
'string'.is();        //=> 'String'
'string'.is(Object);  //=> false
 (function(){}).is(); //=> Function
 var f = function(){};
 f.is(Function);      //=> true
 // also
 function Animal(name){this.name = name || 'some animal';}
 var dog = new Animal('Bello');
 dog.is(Animal); //=> true
 // etc...
```

[**Edit**] tested this in IE7-10:

```
Object.prototype.is = function (test) {
    return test 
      ? this.constructor === test 
      : (this.constructor.name || 
         String(this.constructor)
             .match ( /^function\s*([^\s(]+)/im)[1] );
};
```

for completeness: if the constructor function is anonymous the method will fail. Here's a solution for that:

```
Object.prototype.is = function (test) {
        return test 
          ? this.constructor === test 
          : (this.constructor.name || 
              ( String(this.constructor).match ( /^function\s*([^\s(]+)/im) 
               || ['','ANONYMOUS_CONSTRUCTOR'] ) [1] );
};
// usage
var Some = function(){ /* ... */}
    some = new Some;
some.is(); //=> 'ANONYMOUS_CONSTRUCTOR'
```

And as bonus:

```
Object.prototype.is = function() {
        var test = arguments.length ? [].slice.call(arguments) : null
           ,self = this.constructor;
        return test ? !!(test.filter(function(a){return a === self}).length)
               : (this.constructor.name ||
                  (String(self).match ( /^function\s*([^\s(]+)/im)
                    || [0,'ANONYMOUS_CONSTRUCTOR']) [1] );
}
// usage
var Some = function(){ /* ... */}
   ,Other = function(){ /* ... */}
   ,some = new Some;
2..is(String,Function,RegExp);        //=> false
2..is(String,Function,Number,RegExp); //=> true
some.is();                            //=> 'ANONYMOUS_CONSTRUCTOR'
some.is(Other);                       //=> false
some.is(Some);                        //=> true
// note: you can't use this for NaN (NaN === Number)
(+'ab2').is(Number);                 //=> true
```

Comment: Where can I find more information on constructor.name?  Is it more or less compatible as Object.prototype.toString.call(o)?

Comment: I suppose its less compatible when it concerns IE. But well, everything is [less compatible when it concerns IE], right? Maybe, if it has to be IE-compatible, you should rewrite the method to use `Object.prototype.toString.call(o)` when `constructor.name` fails. Or just ditch IE-compatibility, that browser will never be up to standards.

Comment: I've added a working IE tweak. The browser may not deserve it, the user does.

Comment: Can you consolidate this into one or two methods.  Check our http://underscorejs.org/ as one go-by.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can run into issues when checking arrays across frames in IE 7 and older, so if you want to make it accurate for that case, check out [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4029057).